# Error in train unused arguments R language

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to run R Script were I am getting a train error:

> Error in train(frm, data = mushrooms[train_idx, ], method = "rpart",
>   trControl = trControl,  :    unused arguments (data =
>   mushrooms[train_idx, ], method = "rpart", trControl = trControl,
>   tuneGrid = rpart.grid, metric = "Accuracy")

What I have tried is, please find below. For the dataset, see attachment. [dataset to download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Z7gUzrH5vZXxoe-WJtlA1x_jN0IDRPZ/view?usp=sharing)

```
caret, ggplot2, dplyr, gridExtra, gmodels, ggparallel, rpart.plot, sqldf, readxl
mushrooms <- read_excel("~/Desktop/Rlang/Mushroom.xlsx")
View(mushrooms)
fields <- c("class",
            "cap_shape",
            "cap_surface",
            "cap_color",
            "bruises",
            "odor",
            "gill_attachment",
            "gill_spacing",
            "gill_size",
            "gill_color",
            "stalk_shape",
            "stalk_root",
            "stalk_surface_above_ring",
            "stalk_surface_below_ring",
            "stalk_color_above_ring",
            "stalk_color_below_ring",
            "veil_type",
            "veil_color",
            "ring_number",
            "ring_type",
            "spore_print_color",
            "population",
            "habitat")

colnames(mushrooms) <- fields

set.seed(1023)
train_idx <- createDataPartition(mushrooms$class, p=0.6, list=FALSE)
trControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",  number=10, repeats=5, verboseIter=TRUE)

frm <- paste("class ~ ", paste(relevant_features, collapse="+"))
frm

rpart.grid <- expand.grid(.cp=0)

rpart_fit <- train(frm, 
                     data = mushrooms[train_idx,], 
                     method ="rpart", 
                     trControl = trControl,
                     tuneGrid=rpart.grid,
                     metric = 'Accuracy')
```

Comment: You are passing a character string as `frm` and thus the default method is used which does not have a `data` parameter. You appear to want to use the formula method of `train`, thus you need to pass a formula. Use `as.formula`.

Comment: thanks, but still getting error for at as.formula frm <- as.formula(paste("class ~ ", paste(relevant_features, collapse="+")))

Comment: Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: class ~  
   ^

Comment: You don't show how `relevant_features` is defined. `relevant_features <- c("x", "y"); frm <- as.formula(paste("class ~ ", paste(relevant_features, collapse="+"))) ` works fine.

Comment: Btw, I would use `class ~ .` as the formula and subset the data.frame as `mushrooms[train_idx, c("class", relevant_features)]` .

Comment: still getting same error as Error in train(frm, data = mushrooms[train_idx, ], method = "rpart", trControl = trControl,  : 
  unused arguments (data = mushrooms[train_idx, ], method = "rpart", trControl = trControl, tuneGrid = rpart.grid, metric = "Accuracy")

Comment: i have added relevant_features <- c("x", "y")

Answer (score 1):

Biggest problem in your code was the frm call. As @Roland said, you need to do `as.formula`. The code below works. I also included a part to remove zero variance columns as these are in the way when using train with a formula call when setting contrasts.

```
library(readxl)
mushrooms <- read_excel("Mushroom.xlsx")

fields <- c("class",
            "cap_shape",
            "cap_surface",
            "cap_color",
            "bruises",
            "odor",
            "gill_attachment",
            "gill_spacing",
            "gill_size",
            "gill_color",
            "stalk_shape",
            "stalk_root",
            "stalk_surface_above_ring",
            "stalk_surface_below_ring",
            "stalk_color_above_ring",
            "stalk_color_below_ring",
            "veil_type",
            "veil_color",
            "ring_number",
            "ring_type",
            "spore_print_color",
            "population",
            "habitat")

colnames(mushrooms) <- fields

library(caret)
library(rpart)

y <- "class"
cols_to_remove <- names(mushrooms)[nearZeroVar(mushrooms)]

#[1] "gill_attachment" "veil_type"       "veil_color"  

relevant_features <- setdiff(names(mushrooms), c(y, cols_to_remove))

mushrooms$class <- as.factor(mushrooms$class)

set.seed(1023)
train_idx <- createDataPartition(mushrooms$class, p=0.6, list=FALSE)
trControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",  number=10, repeats=5, verboseIter=TRUE)

frm <- as.formula(paste("class ~ ", paste(relevant_features, collapse="+")))

rpart.grid <- expand.grid(.cp=0)

rpart_fit <- train(frm, 
                   data = mushrooms[train_idx, ], 
                   method ="rpart", 
                   trControl = trControl,
                   tuneGrid=rpart.grid,
                   metric = "Accuracy")
```

Comment: > [1] "gill_attachment" "veil_type"       "veil_color"  
Error: unexpected '[' in "["

Comment: this part is what is in cols_to_remove. not to be run as code. I have commented it so it doesn't interfere anymore.

Comment: thanks, but showing error as Error: unexpected '[' in "["

Comment: copy the script again. the line has been commented